# Azure App Service - deployment from a specific branch in GitHub

Tags: azure, github

I wonder - is there a way to pick up the code from a specific branch only? If I am right, if I follow the following tutorial [Deploying-from-GitHub](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deploying-from-GitHub) push to any branch gets picked up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if you would use [Azure Portal](https://github.com/blog/2056-automating-code-deployment-with-github-and-azure) to configure this, you can select a branch to deploy from. If you are using ARM templates, you can also specify branch:

```
"properties": {
            "RepoUrl": "[parameters('repoURL')]",
            "branch": "[parameters('branch')]",
            "IsManualIntegration": true
          }
```

Comment: Well, if you are using Webhooks and configuring as described in the flow above, in the portal you are selecting Local Git Repository and there is no ability to select branch ;-) I agree that if I connect to GitHub directly from portal (without all the hooks fun), I can select branch, but I would like to avoid this...

Comment: well, don't use local git, whats the issue? webhooks are available for github. updated my answer with a link to "how-to configure github" it also shows you can select a branch

Answer (score 0):

to get it working for local git deployment option, here is the answer: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deployment-branch

> you can set the branch by setting an Azure App Setting called
>   `deployment_branch`.